# Data transformation horizontal to vertical javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help in transforming data in a particular way to plot a graph. The data which I get from API is a different format. Please guide me on how to transform it

```
const demo = [
  {
    label: 'ABC',
    vMini: 28,
    vMaxi: 56,
    dMini: 2,
    dMaxi: 50,
  },
  {
    label: 'BCD',
    vMini: 2,
    vMaxi: 56,
    dMini: 3,
    dMaxi: 50,
  },
];
```

end result which i want is

```
[
  {
    section: "vMini",
    "ABC": 28,
    "BCD": 2,
  },
  {
    section: "vMaxi",
    "ABC": 56,
    "BCD": 56
  }
  {
    section: "dMini",
    "ABC": 2,
    "BCD": 3,
  },
  {
    section: "dMaxi",
    "ABC": 50,
    "BCD": 50
  }
]
```

I have started working on it and got confused with second loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < demo.length; i += 1) {
  for (let j in demo[i]) {
    if (j === 'label') {
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky with the way the data is structured, but you should be able to do this with [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), like so:

```js
const demo = [{label:"ABC",vMini:28,vMaxi:56,dMini:2,dMaxi:50},{label:"BCD",vMini:2,vMaxi:56,dMini:3,dMaxi:50}];

// get array of keys, and create a new object for each one except label
// ["label", "vMini", "vMaxi", "dMini", "dMaxi"]
let results = Object.keys(demo[0]).reduce((res, key) => {
  if (key === "label") { return res; }
  else {
    // for each item in demo, create a key for the label and grab the key's value
    let newObj = demo.reduce((_res, obj) => { 
      _res[obj.label] = obj[key];
      return _res;
    }, {section: key})
    // push the new object into the results array
    res.push(newObj);
  }
  return res;
}, [])

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const demo = [{label:"ABC",vMini:28,vMaxi:56,dMini:2,dMaxi:50},{label:"BCD",vMini:2,vMaxi:56,dMini:3,dMaxi:50}];

const resMap = demo.reduce((a, v) => {
  let label = v.label
  for (let k in v) {
    if (k == 'label') continue
    a.has(k) || a.set(k, { section: k })
    let o = a.get(k)
    o[label] = v[k]
  }
  return a
}, new Map())

const resArr = [...resMap.values()]

console.log(resArr)
```